# block the user from changing the name of a file

Tags: linux, command

Is there any command in linux that can block the user from changing the name of a file. I tried to use

```
chmod -v 000
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ext4 filesystems then you can make the file immutable:

chattr +i

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fedora-linux/0596526822/ch08s04.html